# Grails Taglib testing using GroovyPagesTestCase

Tags: grails

Given a Grails 1.3.7 taglib as follows,

```
package grailsworld

class FooTagLib {   
    def bar =  { attrs, body ->
        out << "<p>Hello World!</p>"
    }
}
```

Why following testcase fails?

```
package grailsworld

import grails.test.*;

class FooTagLibGSPTests extends GroovyPagesTestCase {

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testBar1(){
        def template = '<g:bar/>'
        assertOutputEquals( '<p>Hello World!</p>', template)
    }
}
```

exception is

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at grails.test.GroovyPagesTestCase.applyTemplate(GroovyPagesTestCase.groovy:68)
    at grails.test.GroovyPagesTestCase$applyTemplate.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grails.test.GroovyPagesTestCase.assertOutputEquals(GroovyPagesTestCase.groovy:51)
    at grails.test.GroovyPagesTestCase.assertOutputEquals(GroovyPagesTestCase.groovy)
    at grails.test.GroovyPagesTestCase$assertOutputEquals.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grailsworld.FooTagLibGSPTests.testBar1(FooTagLibGSPTests.groovy:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious question to ask here is whether you are running this test as a unit test or as an integration test. As [noted in the Testing section of the User Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing), GroovyPagesTestCase needs to be run as an integration test, rather than a unit test.

In particular, it relies on a `GroovyPagesTemplateEngine` being injected into the test class and a request context being set in the [RequestContextHolder](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java). The latter you may be able to fake out [similar to the what the MvcUnitTestCase does](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-testing/src/main/groovy/grails/test/MvcUnitTestCase.groovy#L122), the former, though, I am unsure how you can address without making the test an integration test (it really depends on the dependencies of `GroovyPagesTemplateEngine`).

Of course, if you really are trying to unit test such a simple TagLib, it may be easier just to follow the suggestion [also found in the User Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing), and do something like this:

```
class FooTabLibTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testBar1() {
        assertEquals "<p>Hello World!</p>", new FooTagLib().bar(null, null).toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right. I already have an unit test-case using TagLibUnitTestCase. I should have added this one as an Integration test-case. Thank you.